# Change the default gradle folder path used by flutter

Tags: gradle, flutter

Flutter is using `C:\Users\me\\.gradle` folder by default and I'd like to move that folder to `D:\\.gradle`. Simply moving the folder breaks Flutter, as it still looks for the previous location.

I set gradle's user home to `D:\\.gradle` (using the gradle console), but it seems that flutter is not affected by it.
I'm guessing I should make the change in one of the two:

`flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle`

`my_flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat` (or any of the other gradle files)

But I can't find where to change it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Set environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to `D:\.gradle` [whatever location you want] and delete default gradle folder i.e. `C:\Users\me\.gradle`.
Next time you do a build, everything will be setup to new gradle location.

Comment: Also set the Gradle folder location in Android Studio settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle